# Unable to store the Facebook profile picture in sql database

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As you can see the code below retrieve and shows all the required information from a Facebook profile..
Access Token: 
User ID: 
Name: Aneesh 
First Name: 
Last Name: 
Email: 
Gender: 
Birthday:
Location: N
Time Zone:

but i am not able to store the profile picture in sql database ?

```
<?php
require 'lib/db.php';
require 'lib/facebook.php';
require 'lib/fbconfig.php';
session_start();
$facebook=$_SESSION['facebook'];
$userdata=$_SESSION['userdata'];
$logoutUrl=$_SESSION['logout'];
$access_token_title='fb_'.$facebook_appid.'_access_token';
$access_token=$facebook[$access_token_title];


if(!empty($userdata))
{
echo '<h1>Login User Details</h1>';
echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userdata['id'].'/picture">';
```

At the moment the above the code displays the image...but how to store is the problem
I used BLOB which showed  error

```
echo "<br/>";
echo '<b>Access Token: </b>'.$access_token;
echo "<br/>";
echo '<b>User ID: </b>'.$userdata['id'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Name: </b>'.$userdata['name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>First Name: </b>'.$userdata['first_name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Last Name: </b>'.$userdata['last_name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Email: </b>'.$userdata['email'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Gender: </b>'.$userdata['gender'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Birthday: </b>'.$userdata['birthday'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Location: </b>'.$userdata['location']['name'];
echo "<br/>";
echo  '<b>Time Zone: </b>'.$userdata['timezone'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

$facebook_id=$userdata['id'];
$name=$userdata['name'];
$email=$userdata['email'];
$gender=$userdata['gender'];
$birthday=$userdata['birthday'];
$location=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['location']['name']);
$hometown=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['hometown']['name']);
$bio=mysql_real_escape_string($userdata['bio']);
$relationship=$userdata['relationship_status'];
$timezone=$userdata['timezone'];


$inserty = "INSERT INTO `users` (`facebook_id`, `name`, `email`, `gender`, `birthday`, `location`,`timezone`, `access_token`,`??????`) 
VALUES ('$facebook_id','$name','$email','$gender','$birthday','$location','$timezone','$access_token',`?????`)";
mysql_query($inserty, $connection);
```

????? I meant column for image

```
echo "<br/>";

 echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout Facebook</a>';
 echo '<a href="http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/Mosaic/logout.php">Logout Facebook</a>';
 include('status_update.php');
 }
 else
 {
  header("Location: fblogin.php");
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you try to narrow your problem down a bit - it's either retrieving the image (in which case, remove the Db stuff) or storing an image in the Db (in which case, remove the Fb stuff). What errors are you seeing? What have you tried? Sometimes the easiest way to track down a problem is to break the process into testable steps. Eg Did the picture download Ok? Did the picture get stored in the database? Can it be read from the Db? Why isn't it being displayed...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to store the binary data for the image itself, instead of the URL to the image. Ideally, you shouldn't store the image / URL as it's ever-changing on Facebook. Depending on the user, it may change everyday! You can get the current image easily using the API or Facebook ID.

If you must store it, you should store the URL to the Facebook version rather than the image itself.

If you still want to store the image in the DB, try using the `BINARY` type instead.